# WPF > WEBAPI > HttpClient > AWAIT = UI Delay

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, asp.net-web-api

I'm stumped and I need your help.

I have a WPF application that calls a WEBAPI using ASYNC & AWAIT and my UI is experiencing delays.

Here is the code I'm using...

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await WEBAPI.GetHttpClient().GetAsync("api/COStateType/GetStateTypesByCountryID/" + Constants.COUNTRY_ID_USA);  
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 
App.stateTypes = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<coStateType>>();
```

The GetHttpClient code...

```
 public static HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ABS2.WEBAPI.Uri"]);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        return client;
    }
```

Here is the main issue...

During startup I display a splash screen with moving gears (animation).  After implementing the call to the WEBAPI that animation is no longer smooth.  I have read that the ASYNC calls using the HttpClient cause UI blocking and figure that was what is happening to my animation.

Here is the question...

Is there anyway around this issue?  I've tried wrapping this call within a BackgroundWorker and/or Task but neither resolved the issue.  Is there another way to communicate with the WEBAPI that will NOT cause this UI blocking?  An I doing something wrong?

Many, many thanks for any and all help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Stef7 & @Panagiotis - You guys are right that the UI thread was blocked.  I'm not sure I understand why an async call blocks the UI thread though; I'll have to do more research.

I had already tried a Background thread but that didn't resolve my issue until I implemented ContinueWith on the Task.

Thank you for your help.

Here is the final code.

```
public partial class Splash : Window
{
    private TypeBO boType = new TypeBO();
    private Stopwatch swTotal = new Stopwatch();
    private Stopwatch swData= new Stopwatch();

    public Splash()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        swTotal.Start();
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        lblMessage.Content = "Please Wait...";
        lblVersion.Content = "Version: " + assembly.GetName().Version.Major + "." + assembly.GetName().Version.Minor + "." + assembly.GetName().Version.Revision;

        swData.Start();

        var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += this.OnBackgroundWorkerDoWork;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += OnBackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void OnBackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        WEBAPI.GetHttpClient().GetAsync("api/COStateType/GetStateTypesByCountryID/"
            + Constants.COUNTRY_ID_USA).ContinueWith(r =>
            {
                r.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                e.Result = r.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<coStateType>>().Result;
            }).Wait();

        swData.Stop();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Splash - DATA - Total Elapsed Time - " + swData.Elapsed + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void OnBackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork -= this.OnBackgroundWorkerDoWork;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted -= OnBackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted;

        App.stateTypes = e.Result as List<coStateType>;

        coStateType pleaseSelectStateType = new coStateType() { State_ID = 0, State_Nm = "Select One", Country_ID = 1 };
        App.stateTypes.Insert(0, pleaseSelectStateType);

        sbHideState.Completed += (snd, eva) =>
        {
            //Pre-Load User Controls
            Assembly assembly = this.GetType().Assembly;
            UserControl ucBHSearch = (UserControl)assembly.CreateInstance(string.Format("{0}.BHSearch", "ABS2.WPF.ADMIN.UserControls.BusinessHierarchy"));
            UserControl ucBHDetails = (UserControl)assembly.CreateInstance(string.Format("{0}.BHDetails", "ABS2.WPF.ADMIN.UserControls.BusinessHierarchy"));
            App.userControls.Add("BHD", ucBHDetails);
            App.userControls.Add("BHS", ucBHSearch);

            Login winLogin = new Login();
            winLogin.Show();

            swTotal.Stop();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Splash - UI - Total Elapsed Time - " + swTotal.Elapsed + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            swTotal.Reset();
            this.Close();
        };
        sbHideState.Begin(gridSplash);
    }

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblMessage.Content = "";
        lblVersion.Content = "";
        sbDefaultState.Begin(gridSplash);
        sbRotateState.Begin(gridSplash);           
    }

    private void window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sbShowState.Completed += (snd, eva) =>
        {
            GetData();
        };
        sbShowState.Begin(gridSplash);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use a "Task" function to call Async.  This will not block your GUI main thread and you don't need to use background worker or thread either. "Task", "Async", "Await" go together.

Answer (score 1):

When an *await* finishes waiting, execution continues in the original context (thread), which in your case is the UI thread.

This allows your code to access UI controls without using the dispatcher. This means that any expensive code after the last *await* will actually run on the UI thread.

If you want your code to continue running on a separate thread, you should add .ConfigureAwait(false) after the call to await, ie.

```
await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<coStateType>>().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

In this case you should take care to access UI controls using the Dispatcher or the SynchronizationContext methods [Post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx)/[Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send.aspx), eg.

```
SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(_=>progressBar.Value+=5,null);
```

Answer (score 1):

All your posted code is executed in the UI thread. The async feature helps you not blocking the UI thread while it has nothing to do (during the web request), but if you keep the UI thread busy with too much code, your animation will always get problems.

I would try moving all the web related code into a background worker and posting only short UI updates to the UI thread. Since you wrote that you already tried a background worker, I have to assume the UI updates take too long.

If you have a performance profiler, analyze the busy times of the UI thread to get a better picture.